# How to delete specific models in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

I need to delete all the records from A and its related models except some model/s.

For e.g.

A is a parent model :

There are some related models with relation for e.g.

B -> hasOne

C -> hasMany

D -> hasOne

What if I want to remove A along with B and C but not D.

```
A::deleteAll("some condition");
```

So the above line should delete A, B, and C but not D.

I saw documentation of Yii2, but it is not that good.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do that in your database, "ON DELETE...".

Comment: did you write custom trigger in your database ?

Comment: No there are relations with each other and deleteAll will find those related models in parent model and delete respective entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#deleting-data

`Customer::deleteAll(['status' => Customer::STATUS_INACTIVE]);`

The condition is put in the way as described here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

DeleteAll works directly on the database so - as some comments suggest - deleting related records on the fly would be possible by using triggers on SQL level - provided you use SQL. I would not recommend this as this would be magic behaviour that is not apparent from the PHP code itself unless well documented.

Unless you have triggers or foreign keys specified to CASCADE ON DELETE for B and C would A::deleteAll() would only affect the table related to A.

As I said, the ActiveRecord::deleteAll(), does not create instances of ActiveRecord but writes to DB instead.
You could create logic like this, using the each function so you do create instances of A, while preserving memory using the batch functionality:

```
$transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
$condition = []; // your condition to find A

foreach(A::find()->where($condition)->joinWith(['b','c'])->each() as $a) {
   foreach($a->getB()->each() as $b) {
      $b->delete();
   }
   foreach($a->getC()->each() as $c) {
      $c->delete();
   }
   $a->delete();
}
$transaction->commit();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#each()-detail